# bash history not recording failed or erroneous commands

Tags: bash, command-history

I used to be able to use `up` and `down` arrow to find my history, including failed commands that did return a different retval, correct them and try again.
After I installed `fzf` something changed, and now I only have successful commands in my history which return a value, everything else simply isn't there.

I suspect I've either changed something in one of my script configs, or fzf changed something:

- `.bashrc`
- `.fzf.bash`
- `.profile`
- `.bash_profile`

Unfortunately this is extremely annoying and I've no idea how to fix it.
For example, typing:

```bsh
which python
sudo apt-cache
```

produces in `.bash_history`:

```
#1601901660
which python
```

but not the `sudo apt-cache` command.

Running the following command:

```
 grep HIST ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment .fzf.bash 2>/dev/null
```

Produces:

```
/home/tons/.bashrc:HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
/home/tons/.bashrc:HISTSIZE=
/home/tons/.bashrc:HISTFILESIZE=
/home/tons/.bashrc:export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%h %d %H:%M:%S "
/home/tons/.bashrc:export HISTSIZE=10000
/home/tons/.bashrc:export HISTFILESIZE=10000
/home/tons/.bashrc:export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:erasedups
/home/tons/.bashrc:export HISTIGNORE="ls:ps:history"
/home/tons/.bashrc:export HISTIGNORE="s*"
```

Comment: Please post the output of `grep HIST  ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment .fzf.bash 2>/dev/null` so we can see your history settings.

Comment: @terdon thanks for the help, much appreciated! I suspect it's `HISTIGNORE` that changed something?

Comment: `HISTIGNORE="s*"` should explain missing `sudo`. But not commands starting with something other than an s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HISTIGNORE` variable is a way of telling bash's history system to ignore certain commands. Here, you are setting that to:

```
export HISTIGNORE="s*"
```

Note that this will overwrite the earlier `HISTIGNORE="ls:ps:history"`. More importantly, this `s*` tells bash not to store any commands starting with `s` in the history, which nicely explains why your `sudo apt-cache` isn't stored: `sudo` starts with an `s`.

Comment: That explains a lot, I don't even know how that ended up in there (most likely a copy-paste from https://www.shellhacks.com/tune-command-line-history-bash/). EDIT: yes I'm an idiot I blindly copied the lines from the above blogpost!